# Please help me with the diet plan plan

Tags: weight-loss, diet, nutrition

I am gym beginner and my trainer suggested to me the following diet plan with about 400g protein. I am 210 lbs and 6 ft tall guy

- **07:00Am** - 1 Scoop Protein, 60g oats, 10 Almonds, 4 Walnuts
- **08:10Am** - 1 Scoop pre Workout
- **09:30Am** - 1 Scoop Protein, 1 Apple
- **10:30Am** - 4 Brown bread cottage cheese sandwich
- **01:30Pm** - 500g Chicken, 2 Chapati, Salad
- **05:00Pm** - 1 Apple, 5 eggs
- **07:30Pm** - 1 orange, 1 Scoop protein
- **09:30Pm** - 500g Chicken, Salad

Comment: First of all 400 gr protein too much for a beginner. To help you about your plan we should know about your body fat percentage and your goal. U should provide them.

Answer (score -1):

That's not 400gr protein.
Besides, 400gr for a beginner trainer is way too much, try to aim for 1-1.25gr protein per pound (lean mass) bw.

I also would suggest to divide your calorie intake some more, meal 2,3,6,7 hardly contain calories.